# Replacing a block inside a block

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, block

I have created a class that is defined like this:

**HEADER**

```
typedef void (^myBlock)(NSString *value);

- (instancetype)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
                    runOnSelection:(myBlock)runOnSelection;
```

When I init an object of this kind I do:

```
MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"my id"
         runOnSelection:^(NSString *value){
                                doThis();
                                doStuff();
                               doSomethingElse();
        }];
```

The problem is that I have a lot of objects in sequence being initialized like this and all do the same thing.

I was thinking on creating a block for `doThis`, `doStuff` and `doSomethingElse`, like this:

```
void (^doALot)(NSString *value) = ^void(NSString *value) {
                doThis();
                doStuff();
                doSomethingElse();
};
```

and replace the initializations with something like

```
MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"my id"
         runOnSelection:doALot()];
```

but the problem is that `doALot` require a parameter. How do I attach a block to something like that?

I know I can do

```
MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"my id"
         runOnSelection:^(NSString *value){
                  doALot(value)
       }];
```

But I am wondering if I can do this without having to put it inside the block, by simply connecting the two. If I am not wrong, I have seen Apple doing this when they have APIs that have handlers, you can define the handler outside or inside,  so I suspect this is possible.

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new block object like below-

```
typedef void (^myBlock)(NSString *value);

myBlock block=^(NSString *value){
    doThis();
    doStuff();
    doSomethingElse();
};
```

and replace the initialisations with something like

```
MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"my id"
         runOnSelection:block];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: wow, that is insane but works... I would love to know the logic of this

Comment: We simply passing block as a normal object.